# No clickable 'run'/'step' button showing up in PyCX simulator GUI

Tags: python-2.7, backend, spyder, pycxx, pycxsimulator

All code can run without error messages, but the pycxsimulator GUI doesn't generate clickable tabs or 'run' buttons to visualize the simulation, even though the plot does indeed show up.

I think it is a backend issue (which I have been having, and had to downgrade from Python 3.5 to 2.7) with the Tkinter module / "Tk interface" / Tk GUI for python.

Screenshot of issue. Using: MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 on baseline MacBook mid-2017, Python 2.7 installed using Anaconda, Spyder 3.0.0 interface, any standard model from standard PyCX 0.32 folder.
  [image: screenshot]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You should run your script in a real terminal (i.e. not inside the terminal provided by Spyder) to avoid this problem.

Comment: Hi Carlos--thank you so much for your reply. I just tried this and the same issue still occurs when I execute the script from a real Terminal... I look forward to any future help you can provide.

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting to work in a real terminal. I have no more advice to give you.